# Excel VBA Execute custom menu item when editing within a cell

Tags: excel, vba, menu

I have added a custom right button click menu item to the context menu when within a Cell as per:

```
Private Sub AddTheMenuItem(myCommandBar As Office.CommandBar, caption As String, action As String)
    Dim NewControl As CommandBarButton

    Set NewControl = myCommandBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, temporary:=True)

    With NewControl
        .caption = caption
        .OnAction = action
        .Picture = Application.CommandBars.GetImageMso("WrapText", 16, 16)
        .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
    End With

End Sub
```

The menu items display fine, but none of the subs execute. I just get a 'ping' sound. I have tried playing about with using peekmessage and I can see the right button click that brings up the menu, but not the left button click that chooses the menu item. It seems that the message does not get passed to any VBA code that is waiting.

I suppose that the way I am trying to achieve this will not work, but I would like any advice as to some way of getting this to work. For my application it is important to provide users with the appropriate menu items when within a cell.

Thank you in advance,

AZ

Comment: Works fine for me.  Are you sure that the sub you are trying to reach is in the appropriate scope?

Comment: When I modify the 'outside' "Cell" menu the subs execute fine, it is only when I try and invoke the new right button click menus when within a cell, then I only get a 'ping' sound.

Comment: Thank you Layman Coder, could you be more explicit. I have modified the 'Formula Bar' right click menu which is active when you are editing the cell content and the subs that I am trying to execute are public and visible, but will not execute - I just get a 'ping' sound from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Make shure your onAction value is a String or it will be launched at menu setup.
    .OnAction = subName    will fail
whereas
    .OnAction = "subName"    will succeed
as long as 
    Sub subName
is in an Object module and not in the Sheet or Workbook module.